Is the Urysohn lemma a proof by induction or not?

Although Munkres claims that he uses induction and the above step resembles the inductive step of mathematical induction, it is not a proof by induction. Actually we have to make infinitely many choices in extending pairs $(P',\phi')$ to a bigger pairs
$(P'',\phi'')$ and we therefore need the axiom of choice to get the desired $\phi : P \to  \mathcal T_X$.Refer

. I understand the proof of Urysohn Lemma in three parts:

Constructing a system of indexed sets with some properties

Constructing a function who evaluates on elements by giving the smallest index of the set that the element belongs too

Showing that this function is continous


It is quite unintuitive to me that 1. does not use induction. How can one understand the idea that altho we have an infinite recursion thing going on that we don't use any induction?

This is a good question about a slightly subtle point. The point being made in the text that you quote is that if you can prove that, for every $n$, the existence of a sequence of partial functions $\langle \phi_0, \phi_1, \phi_2, \ldots, \phi_{n-1}\rangle $ each of which extends its predecessor implies that there is a partial function $\phi_{n}$ that extends $\phi_{n-1}$, then this does not imply that there exists a function $\phi$ that is the union of all these functions. Some form of the axiom of choice is required to give us the desired $\phi$ (the axiom of dependent choice is sufficient in the case in point).

So it's an inductive construction + additional choice?

No. The argument verifies the hypotheses of the axiom of dependent  choice and then the axiom is applied to give the result. Essentially, what you are calling an "inductive construction" is an appeal to the axiom of dependent choice.
